# PHP foreach loop giving only 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have this array:

```
$cust = xtc_db_query("SELECT customers_id FROM orders");
$customers = xtc_db_fetch_array($cust);
```

When I try to display every single record I get only the first one:

```
foreach ($customers as $v) {
    echo "ID: $v.\n <br>";
}
```

I tried setting the array manually and then it works fine:

```
$customers = array(1, 2, 3, 17);
```

Comment: Would need to know the functions you are using to do db fetches, but initially try a print_r($customers); to check it is bringing back an array. I would expect that the class would return either a row (so an array with one value in it) or the entire record set as an array of arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `$customers` array will only ever contain one value (the last result from the query). You'll need to use a while loop:

```
$cust = xtc_db_query("SELECT customers_id FROM orders");
while($customers = xtc_db_fetch_array($cust))
{
    // Use $customers here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$cust = xtc_db_query("SELECT customers_id FROM orders");
while($customers = xtc_db_fetch_array($cust)){
   echo "ID: $customers[customers_id].\n <br>";
}
```

Comment: echo "ID: $customers.\n <br>"; gives me ID: Array. I had to change it to echo "ID: $customers[customers_id].\n <br>";. Thanks for the answer though, I got it working

Answer (score 0):

`xtc_db_fetch_array` will return one record in every iteration.

To get all the records, you'll have to put `xtc_db_fetch_array($cust)` in while loop like below.

```
$cust = xtc_db_query("SELECT customers_id FROM orders");
while($customers = xtc_db_fetch_array($cust)){
    print_r($customers);
}
```